# RunWorkerCompleted fired before async void Dowork event

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm using A background worker for BLE RSSI level test.

my problem is that RunWorkerCompleted event is fired immediately, way before DoWork done it's operation.

most of the DoWork event operation is to create an advertisement watcher and wait for Signal from A Bluetooth low energy device.
the signal level will be updated fromthe main thread and handling of the result will be on the background worker.

here is when I call the Background worker:

```
 ...
  worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += callTestBLE;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(RSSI_Label);
  }
```

The event handlers:

```
private async void callTestBLE(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher1 ;
            BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter advertisementFilter1;
            int rssiRetries1 = RSSIRETRIES;
            RssiValue = "";

            advertisementFilter1 = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter();
            try
            {
                advertisementFilter1.Advertisement.LocalName = myUswm.getAdvetrismentName();
                checkRSSI = true;
            }
            catch (Exception) { checkRSSI = false; return; }

            watcher1 = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher(advertisementFilter);
            watcher1.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;
            watcher1.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
            // Wait 5 seconds to make sure the device is really out of range
            watcher1.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
            watcher1.SignalStrengthFilter.SamplingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

            try
            {
                watcher1.Start(); 
                await testBLEAsync();
                if (myUswm.getConnectionStatus() == DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    checkNextUUTClick(new object(), new RoutedEventArgs()); return;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    // if (RssiSamplesNum <= 0 || --rssiRetries < 0)
                    if (RssiSamplesNum <= 0 || --rssiRetries1 < 0)
                    {
                        //serviceList.Clear();
                        watcher1.Stop();
                        rssiRetries1 = RSSIRETRIES;
                        RssiSamplesNum1 = numOfAdvertismentSamples;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       ((Label)e.Argument).Content = RssiValue;
                        /*RSSI_Label.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        { RSSI_Label.Content = RssiValue; }));*/
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                  }    
            }
    catch (Exception err) { }
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       finalizeBleTest();
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should not interact with UI elements (or call MessageBox.Show ) on the background workers DoWork thread, as this is not the UI thread and will cause problems.

Comment: you are right, code was edited

Comment: `async void` should be used for Fire & *Forget* code, since there's no means for the calling code to track completion. So I'd suggest your `DoWork` method shouldn't be `async`. Use `BackgroundWorker` *or* use `async`/`await`, but in general, don't attempt to combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here with the `async` and `await`. BackgroundWorker is a bit outdated and do not support asynchronous code. So when you await for `testBLEAsync` call, `callTestBLE` method finishes and at that moment you have your `RunWorkerCompleted` event called, while actual code continue to work in the background.

So simplest solution is to completely remove `async`/`await` from your code and everything should work as expected, or, alternatively, you can rewrite your code using tasks and task continuations.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with the other answer that `BackgroundWorker` is not compatible with `async`/`await`. However, I disagree that the simplest solution is to remove `async` in favor of `BackgroundWorker`. IMO, the superior solution (also resulting in simpler code) is to remove `BackgroundWorker` in favor of `async`; specifically, to [replace the outdated `BackgroundWorker` with the superior `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html):

```
// `worker` is now `Task`.
await Task.Run(() => callTestBLE());
finalizeBleTest();
```

where the signature of `callTestBLE` is `async Task`, not `async void`.