# Background worker exiting DoWork before loop is completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, backgroundworker

I have a program that sends a ping object, it sends out the ping request, repeats for each ping object (there's 8), waits 1000ms, and then repeats this for however many seconds the user specifies.

When telling the program to run for a low amount of time 2-3 seconds, the loop works as expected. Outputting the amount of successful pings successfully (if it ran for 2 seconds then I would expect each ping object to have 2 successful pings which they do)

An example of the unexpected behaviour I'm receiving is this, I set the amount of seconds to run as 10, so it should loop through each of the 8 ping objects, wait one second, and repeat this `for count > 10`

I am debugging and the loop works as expected but then suddenly exits after around 6 'seconds'. I can see that `count = 10`, and `i is 6` but then the worker exits and the `RunWorkerCompleted` method is called.

I can think of maybe its a problem with threading(?) but I am unsure.

Here is the background worker `DoWork` method:

```
private async void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Create background worker 
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

        // Write to log file
        await file.WriteAsync("Starting job...\n");
        await file.WriteAsync("Requested amount of pings: " + count + "\n");
        // Create date object for logs
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Create ping objects
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pinger = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
            PingReply pingReply;

            foreach (Ping pingObj in pings)
            {
                try
                {
                    pingReply = pinger.Send(pingObj.IpAddress);
                    // Write log file
                    await file.WriteLineAsync(localDate.TimeOfDay + " | Friendly Name " + pingObj.FriendlyName + " | Ping: " + pingReply.Address + " | Status " + pingReply.Status + " | Time: " + pingReply.RoundtripTime);
                    if (pingReply.Status.ToString().Contains("Success"))
                    {
                        pingObj.SuccessfulPings += 1;
                    }
                    else // Unsuccessful ping has been sent
                    {
                        pingObj.FailedPings += 1;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            wait(1000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here's how I begin the worker, with a button:

```
private void Ping_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 1;
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
    {
        // For every ping object    
        foreach (Ping pinger in pings)
        {
            // Set the appropriate UI element properties
            // Create initial control object
            // Finds controls in which their name matches the string
            Control? ctl = this.Controls.Find("greenBox" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control;
            if (ctl != null)
            {
                ctl.Visible = false;
            }
            ctl = this.Controls.Find("orangeBox" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control;
            if (ctl != null)
            {
                ctl.Visible = false;
            }
            ctl = this.Controls.Find("redBox" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control;
            if (ctl != null)
            {
                ctl.Visible = true;
            }
            ctl = this.Controls.Find("status_Lbl" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control;
            if (ctl != null)
            {
                ctl.Text = "Initiated...";
            }

            counter++;
        }
        // Take input from text box
        count = Convert.ToInt32(pingSeconds_TxtBox.Text);
        // Start operation
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Here is the method for waiting 1000 ms

```
public void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    var timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    if (milliseconds == 0 || milliseconds < 0) return;

    timer1.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();

    timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Stop();
    };

    while (timer1.Enabled)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

The amount of times it loops through seems to be random, I tested it just there after removing the lines just in case the .DoEvents(); line is interfering with the background worker.

```
while (timer1.Enabled)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Ran it as usual with `count = 10` did this twice and the first time it ran through once, and the second time it ran through 7 times.

Any help would be appreciated

**Answer**
Removed background worker and implemented `async/await` instead

- Answer provided by Charlieface

Comment: Related: [RunWorkerCompleted fired before async void Dowork event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154663/runworkercompleted-fired-before-async-void-dowork-event). That question has another Linked question at the right side of the page, that leads to more related questions.

Comment: Why use `wait()` instead of `await Task.Delay(1000);` ? That's completely messing things up for sure.

Comment: Unrelated: `count = Convert.ToInt32(pingSeconds_TxtBox.Text);` - that's bad. Never trust user intput. Use an appropriate control for the type of value you are expecting. And then still validate if it's inside your expected boundaries.

Comment: `async void` and `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` are not going to mix well. Why use a `BackgroundWorker` at all, given that it's deprecated? Do the whole things with `async` and maybe `Task,Run`

Comment: @Fildor await Task.Delay(1000) doesn't have any delay at all when used instead of wait(1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix `async void` and `BackgroundWorker.DoWork`, because as soon as you hit the first `await` then the `DoWork` handler appears to the worker that it has finished.

I would advise you to remove the `BackgroundWorker` entirely, and just use `await`.

There appears to be missing information from your sample code: what are `pings` `count` and `file`? I have tried to guess how that works, but it looks like you are using some kind of cached field for these, which (at least in the case of `file`) is probably inadvisable.

```cs
SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private void Ping_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!await _sem.WaitAsync(0))  // bail-out if already executing
        return;
    try
    {
        int counter = 1;
        // For every ping object    
        foreach (Ping pinger in pings)
        {
            // Set the appropriate UI element properties
            // Create initial control object
            // Finds controls in which their name matches the string
            (this.Controls.Find("greenBox" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control)?.Visible = false;
            (this.Controls.Find("orangeBox" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control)?.Visible = false;
            (this.Controls.Find("redBox" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control)?.Visible = true;
            (this.Controls.Find("status_Lbl" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control)?.Text = "Initiated...";
            counter++;
        }
        // Take input from text box
        count = Convert.ToInt32(pingSeconds_TxtBox.Text);
        // Start operation
        await DoPing();
    }
    finally
    {
        // release lock
        _sem.Release();
    }
}

private async Task DoPing()
{
    try
    {
        // Write to log file
        await file.WriteAsync("Starting job...\n");
        await file.WriteAsync("Requested amount of pings: " + count + "\n");
        // Create date object for logs
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

        using (System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pinger = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                foreach (Ping pingObj in pings)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var pingReply = await pinger.SendAsync(pingObj.IpAddress);
                        // Write log file
                        await file.WriteLineAsync(localDate.TimeOfDay + " | Friendly Name " + pingObj.FriendlyName + " | Ping: " + pingReply.Address + " | Status " + pingReply.Status + " | Time: " + pingReply.RoundtripTime);
                        if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            pingObj.SuccessfulPings += 1;
                        }
                        else // Unsuccessful ping has been sent
                        {
                            pingObj.FailedPings += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It all seems to be working now, guess I did need to make the jump from background worker

Comment: I had no idea that `async/wait` would have such a drastic impact on performance! Gone from around 20-30% CPU usage while running to around ~2%

Comment: You had an infinite loop around `Application.DoEvents` which would explain that