# Await async background thread behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, backgroundworker

I'm updating a C# WPF project that previously used a WCF service and now calls REST-based API.

The following code is a typical example of a REST API call:

```
public static async Task<List<KBase>> GetKbase(int shopID)
{
    // set request
    string uri = ROOT_URI + "kbase/" + shopID.ToString();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token.token);

    // get
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http_client.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        List<KBase> kb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KBase>>(result);
        return kb;
    }
    else
    {
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        gFunc.AddLogEntry("Get Kbase: " + result);
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I call the above API method using the following code, everything happens as expected. The message-box displays **true**.

```
private async void btnTest_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   List<Models.API.KBase> kb = await apiSamadhi.GetKbase(1);
   bool is_data = !(kb == null);
   MessageBox.Show(is_data.ToString());
}
```

However, there are many parts of the program where I use background workers in order to keep the main UI thread responsive. I create the background worker as follows:

```
BackgroundWorker bgw;
List<Models.API.KBase> kb;
private void InitBGW()
{
   bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
   bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
   bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_WorkCompleted;
}
```

The following code shows the DoWork and WorkCompleted methods:

```
private async void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    kbase = await apiSamadhi.GetKbase(1);
}

private void bgw_WorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    bool is_data = !(kbase == null);
    MessageBox.Show(is_data.ToString());
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    is_data = !(kbase == null);
    MessageBox.Show(is_data.ToString());
}
```

When bgw_WorkCompleted runs, **kbase** is null and the first message-box shows **false**. Then after sleeping the thread for a second, **kbase** is NOT null and the second message-box shows **true**.

This is not the behavior I expected. It's like the **await** in bgw_DoWork is not working. Why does bgw_WorkCompleted run BEFORE the 'await'ed call to the API is completed?

Am I missing something or doing something stupid? I need to be able to run 'await'ed API calls/tasks on a non-UI thread and be able to update the UI when the task completes.

---

Despite following the suggested links and reading more on background workers, Async and Await I'm still struggling to get a working solution.

Considering background workers are getting long in the tooth and are ill advised to use along with Async and Await, I've tried using the Task.Run approach. However, the so-called "await"ed tasks are still not completing prior to reaching the end of the method.

In the code below **id** is a global int variable in a static general helper class.

```
static public async void ReloadData()
{
    id = 0;
    await Task.Run(() => InitialiseDaysheet());
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
    await Task.Run(() => LoadDaysheet());
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
    // update ui after loading data
}
```

When the above method runs, the first message-box shows "0" despite code at the end of InitialiseDaysheet() that assigns the value of 50. The second message-box shows "50" yet the end of LoadDaysheet() assigns the value of 100.

InitialiseDaysheet() and LoadDaysheet have a lot of code but within each method there are various API calls as shown below.

```
static private async void InitialiseDaysheet()
{
    // code
    kb = await apiSamadhi.GetKbase(1);
    // code
}
```

Also, adding ConfigureAwait(false) as shown below makes no difference.

```
static private async void InitialiseDaysheet()
{
    // code
    kb = await apiSamadhi.GetKbase(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // code
}
```

Comment: This one blocks the main thread `` response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`` , should be like this: ``await  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()``

Comment: The `await`ed call on the UI thread runs on the UI thread. The `await`ed call on the background worker's `DoWork` is going to run on that worker's thread (I think - no idea how that awaiter works). The `WorkCompleted` call is going to run on the UI thread (including your sleep call!). To figure things out use `Thread.IsBackground` and `Thread.IsPoolThread` in a debug build and trace things out

Comment: This is actually a bit of a guess on my part as I'm not au fait with the finer details of async/await but I wonder whether, because you're not making the call on the UI thread, `kbase = await apiSamadhi.GetKbase(1).Configureawait(false);` would address the issue. Looks like this has been addressed in an answer and I was on the right track.

Comment: Related: [RunWorkerCompleted fired before async void Dowork event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154663/runworkercompleted-fired-before-async-void-dowork-event).

Comment: Also you might find this interesting: [Async/await vs BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker/64620920#64620920 "Async/await vs BackgroundWorker").

Comment: Don't use BackgroundWorker, that API is not needed

Comment: By using `async void` you explicitly state that you don't want that call to be awaited. Wrapping that call in `Task.Run()` will not make it magically awaitable - you waiting for method start, not completion. What is wrong with just using `async Task` or `async Task<T>`?

Comment: @max I'm using async void because I want the code in the method to not interfere with the main UI thread. but my understanding was that each statement in this method would complete before executing the next one. In other words I want a background thread but I need any calls to async methods (such as Web API calls) to complete before the code moves on. anyway, I think I've got a workable solution now without using any legacy background workers.

Answer (score 1):

`BackgroundWorker` expects `DoWork` handler to be blocking, but in case of `async void` it exits before actual async operation is complete and `WorkCompleted` handler is invoked - the real work here is only **starting** the async operation, not waiting for it to complete. `BackgroundWorker` does not play well with `async`/`await`.

You could drop `BackgroundWorker` completely, something like this should do the trick:

```cs
private async void InitBGW()
{
    var kbase = await Task.Run(async () => 
        await apiSamadhi
            .GetKbase(1)
            .ConfigureAwait(false));
    var is_data = kbase is not null;
    MessageBox.Show(is_data.ToString());
}
```

Also, since we have a GUI application here, it will have a `SynchronizationContext`, which means that all non-UI related code should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid getting back to UI thread:

```
await http_client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You don't need to add `ConfigureAwait` when you interact with UI after awaiting:

```
await Task.Run(/* ... */); // no ConfigureAwait() here - get back on UI thread after
MessageBox.Show("good, back to UI thread");
```

And as someone mentioned in comments, there is no reason to call `Task<T>.Result` when you are already in `async` method:

```
string result = await response.Content
   .ReadAsStringAsync()
   .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In case of forgotten `ConfigureAwait` you could get back to UI thread and `.Result` call will simply block it.

And for a final note - you don't always need to wrap everything in `Task.Run()` - only if async operation has long-executing synchronous prefix, which is probably not the case here - you can simply go with

```
var data = await apiSamadhi.GetKbase(1);
```

if you carefully use `ConfigureAwait()` and don't call `Task<T>.Result` on UI thread.

---

Declaring method as `async void` explicitly states that it cannot be awaited - you need something awaitable, like `Task`, to be able to track method completion:

```cs
static private async Task InitialiseDaysheet()
{
    // code
    kb = await apiSamadhi.GetKbase(1);
    // code
}
```

As mentioned before, `Task.Run()` is not required - it was used to mimic the behavior of `BackgroundWorker` more closely.

```
// this one might also be better with changing to async Task,
// but hard to tell from the provided example, depends on usage
static public async void ReloadData()
{
    id = 0;
    await InitialiseDaysheet();
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
    await LoadDaysheet();
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
}
```

`async void` is often used with event handlers because `async` does not change method signature:

```cs
// same signature as without async, but now we can await
// and still be a valid button click handler
async void OnButtonClick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await MyAsyncCall();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        // if we dont handle exceptions in async void - nobody will
        // because nobody can await this call - it looks like a normal
        // sync method to the external observer
    }
}
```

And `ConfigureAwait(false)` has nothing to do with the ability to await the call - it only affects the choice of the thread for the task continuation to run on:

```cs
async void A()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await SomeAsyncMethod();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    // back to UI thread if A() was called from UI thread
}

async void B()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await SomeAsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    // continue on a thread pool thread, don't go back to UI thread
}
```

Comment: Why do an `await` inside a `Task.Run`? If you're awaiting then do that without the `Task.Run`.

Comment: Last note mentions that in wrapping everything in `Task.Run()` is not required. There could be a case of a badly designed async method, that is just a blocking method in disguise - like `Task PretendingToBeAync() { HeavyLongRunningSyncMethod(); return Task.CompletedTask; }`, where wrapping in `Task.Run()` can send those methods to threadpool and unblock the calling thread.